# NumPy: Create a dict() by grouping values in a column by another column values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, grouping

Suppose I have a 2-D NumPy array like the one below:

```
arr = numpy.array([[1,0], [1, 4.6], [2, 10.1], [2, 0], [2, 3.53]])
arr
Out[39]: 
array([[  1.  ,   0.  ],
       [  1.  ,   4.6 ],
       [  2.  ,  10.1 ],
       [  2.  ,   0.  ],
       [  2.  ,   3.53]])
```

What would be the fastest way to group the values in the 2nd column based on the values in the first column and create a dict out of it (the desired output is below)

```
{1: [0, 4.6], 2: [10.1, 0, 3.53]}
```

Currently I use a loop, and because the actual array I have is more than 1 million rows, and the first column has more than 5000 unique values, it's quite slow. I prefer *not* to use pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach -

```
def create_dict(arr):
    a = arr[arr[:,0].argsort()] # sort by col-0 if not already sorted
    s0 = np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(a[1:,0] > a[:-1,0])+1,a.shape[0]]
    ids = a[s0[:-1],0]
    return {ids[i]:a[s0[i]:s0[i+1],1].tolist() for i in range(len(s0)-1)}
```

Sample run -

```
In [64]: arr
Out[64]: 
array([[  2.  ,   0.  ],
       [  1.  ,   4.6 ],
       [  2.  ,  10.1 ],
       [  4.  ,   0.5 ],
       [  1.  ,   0.  ],
       [  4.  ,   0.23],
       [  2.  ,   3.53]])

In [65]: create_dict(arr)
Out[65]: {1.0: [4.6, 0.0], 2.0: [0.0, 10.1, 3.53], 4.0: [0.5, 0.23]}
```

---

**Runtime test**

Other approaches -

```
# @Moinuddin Quadri's soln
def defaultdict_based(arr):
    my_list  = arr.tolist()
    my_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in my_list:
        my_dict[key].append(value)
    return my_dict

# @Psidom's soln
def numpy_split_based(arr):
    sort_arr = arr[arr[:, 0].argsort(), :]
    split_arr = np.split(sort_arr, np.where(np.diff(sort_arr[:,0]))[0] + 1) 
    return {s[0,0]: s[:,1].tolist() for s in split_arr}
```

Timings -

```
# Create sample random array with the first col having 1000000 elems
# with 5000 unique ones as stated in the question
In [102]: arr = np.random.randint(0,5000,(1000000,2))

In [103]: %timeit defaultdict_based(arr)
     ...: %timeit numpy_split_based(arr)
     ...: %timeit create_dict(arr)
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 634 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 270 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 260 ms per loop
```

Bottlenecks for the approaches :

Seems like with `defaultdict` based approach the conversion to `list` with `.tolist()` is proving to be heavy (>50% of total runtime) -

```
In [104]: %timeit arr.tolist()
1 loops, best of 3: 372 ms per loop
```

For the other two approaches the sorting (if needed) at the start alongwith the splitting/loop-comprehension at the end are the time-consuming portions. The sorting step has the runtime  (~50% of total runtime) -

```
In [106]: %timeit arr[arr[:,0].argsort()]
10 loops, best of 3: 140 ms per loop
```

Comment: I would like to know the time difference if `arr.tolist()` is called outside of the function in my solution, because that will be better comparison. Can you please share with me the stats? Also, what if numpy array is used with `defaultdict`? :)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Added timings for that step. Since, the question states NumPy array to be the input, I think for fairness we need to keep within the function call :)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I tested numpy array with defaultdict and it gotten worse at 977msec.

Comment: Thanks. I am glad to know that. My current setup isn't having numpy installed, sorry to bother you for re-calculating the stats. But it is good to have the additional information in the answer :)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri No worries at all! Love to time stuffs :)

Answer (score 3):

You may do it without `numpy` via using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). In-fact based on the example you provided, you don't even need the numpy array. Python's `list` are good enough for your requirement. Below is the example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_list = [[1,0], [1, 4.6], [2, 10.1], [2, 0], [2, 3.53]]

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in my_list:
    my_dict[key].append(value)

    # if you want the values as float in the dict, use:
    #     my_dict[float(key)].append(float(value))
```

where final content hold by `my_dict` will be:

```
{1: [0, 4.6], 2: [10.1, 0, 3.53]}
```

Comment: indeed and way simpler! I don't see the point of using numpy when python itself can do this with a linear complexity in a single iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.split`:

```
# sort array by the first column if it isn't
sort_arr = arr[arr[:, 0].argsort(), :]
​
# split the array and construct the dictionary
split_arr = np.split(sort_arr, np.where(np.diff(sort_arr[:,0]))[0] + 1)

{s[0,0]: s[:,1].tolist() for s in split_arr}
# {1.0: [0.0, 4.6], 2.0: [10.1, 0.0, 3.53]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your first column is in sorted order, this will work.

```
In [165]: d = {}

In [166]: uniq, idx, idxinv, counts = np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_index=True, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

In [167]: [d.update({arr[:, 0][el]: arr[:, 1][range(ix, counts[ix])]}) for ix, el in enumerate(idx)]
Out[167]: [None, None]

In [168]: d
Out[168]: {1.0: array([ 0. ,  4.6]), 2.0: array([  4.6,  10.1])}
```